# Kernel Compile Error on Fedora 18 (on VirtualBox on Macbook)

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, kernel, fedora

I have installed Fedora 18 on VirtualBox on Macbook Pro and wanted to see if the Kernel compile is working fine.

After installing Fedora I had updated the Kernel source etc using the below commands

```
yum install kernel-devel

yum install kernel-headers

yum insall kernel-doc

yum install man
```

My Kernel version is 3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64

I had tried Kernel compile with a simple Hello World program which goes like below

```
/*
 *  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
*/

#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

        /*
         * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
         */
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

WHen I try to compile using the below commands, I get the below error

```
[seemabhat@localhost ~]$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64/build M=/home/seemabhat modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
[seemabhat@localhost ~]$
```

Please suggest what do I need to do

Comment: Add your make file to this post. Error is due to Make file it seems.

Comment: `build` is an softlink for kernel headers. tried manually creating it???

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...problem with your kernel not with your program.....check whether build directory is there or not in /usr/lib/modules/3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64..or if it is there then by clicking it is accessible or not....I believe it won't be there, you updated your kernel parts not kernel itself. Try to use this command "yum install update kernel" without quote, it will update your kernel...you can check lateset version kernel folder after installing in /usr/lib/modules...so when u do uname -r it will still show your previous kernel...so reboot it...and then do uname -r to check latest kernel version running...now try to build your module...It will execute successfully...Good Luck.